# Regex to match property types C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program where I have to check if any automatic property types matches a class name.

So, for example, if I have:

```
public class User 
{
   //Some code here
}


public class Cars
{
  public string Brand {get; set;}
  public string YearModel {get; set;}
  public List<User> HasRented {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I already have the code to match class names, so I can get the name "User" from "public class User". Problem is, I need the regex to get "`List<User>`" from "`public List<User> HasRented {get; set;}`". Of course, I want to get all the property types. So I also want the two "string" to match on the regex.

If it is to any help, I've already got a regex that gets the Name of properties, so maybe someone could help me modify it to get the type of properties instead?

**REGEX:** \w+(?=\s*{\s*get\b)

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that I have the source as a string, which is why I would like to match it with regex. To be extra clear: The ONLY thing that I need help with is the regex to get property types from a text that contains a class filled with automatic properties. Not the matching with the class name.

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly: You have the source as a *string* and want to extract information from it? The code is not compiled into your assembly, so you could use the `Cars` and `User` types directly?

Comment: if you want to extract information from C# source code, why not use Roslyn? seems like it would be more reliable than regex...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Forgot to mention that I have the source as a string.

Comment: public\s(?<type>[^\s]+)\s[^\s]+\s\{[^\}\n]+\}

Comment: Rinecamo I tried your regex on [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) but didn't get a match

Comment: This is tagged C#. So you parse C# code from a C# application? Just to be sure, because you could also parse C# code from a Java application...

Comment: ´The thought is that a user will be able to copy/paste c# code in to my applications textbox. When they press a button, I will take this code, which is actually a string in my program, and match the property type of every property which is in the string. My program is built in c# and uses only c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both name and type with:

```
(?<type>[^\s]+)\s(?<name>[^\s]+)(?=\s\{get;)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hT1aQ1/1)
or just type with:

```
(\S+(?:<.+?>)?)(?=\s\w+\s\{get;)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hT1aQ1/3)

Comment: Thank you! The second regex is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, I needed the first regex too. If I could upvote you two times sir, I would!

Comment: @Jokerish then better modify it to match like second one, check [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/hT1aQ1/4), without it it will not match more complicated generic types

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions to parse code is no use since the type of properties is not limited to 1 level generics and can be anything like

```
List<SortedList<string, User>>
```

in this case, it is better to let the C# compiler (csc) to do the work.

I assume that the code can be compiled of course, since your source code is missing the required using statement for System.Collections.Generic;

Here is the code to compile the source code:

```
    CSharpCodeProvider prov = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerResults results = prov.CompileAssemblyFromFile(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(), new string[] { "c:\\temp\\code.txt" });
    if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
    {
        Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", type.Name);
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    Property: {0}, Return Type: {1}", pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
Type: User
Type: Cars
    Property: Brand, Return Type: System.String
    Property: YearModel, Return Type: System.String
    Property: HasRented, Return Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[User]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my case. In my case, a regex would do it.

Answer (score 0):

regex `^\s*public\s+([^\s]+)\s+[^\s]+\s+\{[^\}\n]+\}` with modifiers global and multiline will return the class names of the properties

Comment: Hi Keith. Maybe I have been a little bit unclear, but I already have the code to check if the returned value from regex matches a class name. The ONLY code that I need is actually the regex to match the type of a property. So if the property is `public string Name { get; set; }` the regex should match `string`. If the property is `public List<User> HasRented { get; set; }` the regex should match `List<User>`. If there is a class that with several properties, the regex should match all the property types in that class